# how can i fill multiple variable with array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

i use vb 2010,i have variable and i want to fill them with array. so, in array is variable.
Example:

```
public rbt_ckd , nozzle_c, carrier_x as integer 
public state(3) as integer      
dim arrayX() as integer = {rbt_ckd,nozzle_c,carrier_x}      

for i as integer = 0 to 2     
    arrayX(i) = state(i)      
next
```

i tried this script format. but it is not work.

How can I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: what was the error you are getting? i think you actually want to fill the `state` array with `rbt_ckd , nozzle_c, carrier_x ` variables, isn't it?

Comment: state(3) has 4 elements not 3 - (0 to 2) is a 3 element loop. 0 to 3 = 4 elements.

Comment: Are you expecting that code to set the value of each variable from the elements of `arrayX`?  If so then you will be disappointed.  If that's what you want then it basically can't be done.

Comment: no, i want to fill variable in arrayx with state array..

Comment: even state have 4 elemet, i only use 3, see i just use : 0 to 2

Comment: jmcilhinney   --- thats why i am asking this...

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Public` for `Dim`:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim rbt_ckd, nozzle_c, carrier_x As Integer
    Dim state(3) As Integer
    state(0) = 10  'sample added
    state(1) = 11  'sample added
    state(2) = 12  'sample added
    Dim arrayX() As Integer = {rbt_ckd, nozzle_c, carrier_x}

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        arrayX(i) = state(i)
    Next

    Debug.Print(rbt_ckd)  ' this will print 0, not 10

End Sub
```

> Note that filling is by value, not by reference. (See the output of added `Debug.Print()`.)